# Seeing ORA-00905: missing keyword error due to CASE statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm seeing a `ORA-00905: missing keyword at` Error at Position: 181 and can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the SQL (Oracle PL/SQL).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FOO
    WHERE LOCATION = :LOCATION
      AND SAVED_DATE >= CASE WHEN :BEGIN_D IS NULL THEN SAVED_DATE ELSE TIMESTAMP :BEGIN_D END
      AND SAVED_DATE <= CASE WHEN :END_D IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE TIMESTAMP :END_D END
 ORDER BY SAVED_DATE;
```

My assumption is that in the event user input is:

```
:LOCATION = 'new york'
:BEGIN_D = NULL
:END_D = NULL
```

then query is deduced to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FOO
    WHERE LOCATION = 'new york'
      AND SAVED_DATE >= SAVED_DATE -- This line is ignored
      AND SAVED_DATE <= SYSDATE
 ORDER BY SAVED_DATE;
```

However I'm seeing the error mentioned at the beginning.

When the input is not `NULL` (Ex: `:BEGIN_D = '2015-12-01 00:01:44'`) I do not see an error. If either or both `:BEGIN_D` and `:END_D` is `NULL` the error comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind variables are not substitution variables; they are not replaced by the text you input so you cannot use `TIMESTAMP :BEGIN_D`. You would just want to use `:BEGIN_D` and pass in a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   FOO
WHERE  LOCATION = :LOCATION
AND    SAVED_DATE >= CASE WHEN :BEGIN_D IS NULL THEN SAVED_DATE ELSE :BEGIN_D END
AND    SAVED_DATE <= CASE WHEN :END_D IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE :END_D END
ORDER BY SAVED_DATE;
```

You also do not need to use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   FOO
WHERE  LOCATION = :LOCATION
AND    (:BEGIN_D IS NULL OR SAVED_DATE >= :BEGIN_D)
AND    ((:END_D IS NULL AND SAVED_DATE <= SYSDATE) OR SAVED_DATE <= :END_D)
ORDER BY SAVED_DATE;
```

---

If you are passing in a string value (and not a timestamp) then use `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   FOO
WHERE  LOCATION = :LOCATION
AND    (:BEGIN_D IS NULL OR SAVED_DATE >= TO_DATE(:BEGIN_D, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
AND    ((:END_D IS NULL AND SAVED_DATE <= SYSDATE) OR SAVED_DATE <= TO_DATE(:END_D, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
ORDER BY SAVED_DATE;
```

Comment: I'm curious, how come `TIMESTAMP :BEGIN_D` doesn't work here but `TO_DATE(:BEGIN_D, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` does?

Comment: @DanteK Because (1) a bind variable is already of the data type of whatever you declared the bind variable as in the client application so it you do not need to clarify the data type when the server parses the SQL statement and (2) putting the keyword `TIMESTAMP` before it is invalid syntax because it does **NOT** substitute your input into the SQL (that is what a substitution variable does).